# Passing onChange events through the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am creating a form component and I want to be able to pass on change elements per form element and I cannot seem to get it work properly.

I have my LoginComponent

```
import React from "react";
import './LoginComponent.css';

import FormComponent from '../FormComponent/FormComponent';

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      header: "Login",
      id: "login-form",
      name: "login-form",
      items: [
        {
          element: "input",
          type: "email",
          id: "lf-email",
          name: "lf-email",
          value: "",
          onChange: this.handleOnChangeEmail.bind(this),
          placeholder: "Email",
          img: {},
        },
        {
          element: "input",
          type: "password",
          id: "lf-password",
          name: "lf-password",
          value: "",
          onChange: ,
          placeholder: "Password",
          img: {},
        },
        {
          element: "checkbox",
          id: "lf-remember-me",
          name: "lf-remember-me",
          value: "lf-remember-me",
          onChange: ,
          display: "Remember Me",
          isSelected: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  // Figure out how to pass onChange functions per item in state.
  handleOnChangeEmail(e) {
     console.log("Email changed");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="LoginComponent">
        {/* 
            Create onSubmit function for submitting the form
            Create handle change functions for inputs
        */}
        <FormComponent id={ this.state.id } name={ this.state.name } onSubmit="" header={ this.state.header } items={ this.state.items } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

As you can see I want to pass in the handle function in the state of the component so I can uniquely handle form inputs. When I run this code though it fails because I cannot pass a function in the state. Is this type of request allowed or able to accomplish in another way?

I know you can pass the bound function to the component directly but the form component is dynamically built based on the state.item array.

Here is my form component

```
import React from "react";
import './FormComponent.css';

import InputComponent from './InputComponent/InputComponent';
import FormHeaderComponent from './FormHeaderComponent/FormHeaderComponent';
import CheckboxComponent from "./CheckboxComponent/CheckboxComponent";

class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const formItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
      switch(item.element) {
        case "input":
          return <InputComponent type={ item.type } id={ item.id } name={ item.name } placeholder={ item.placeholder } value={ item.value } onChange={ item.onChange } />
        case "checkbox":
          return <CheckboxComponent id={ item.id } name={ item.name } value={ item.value } selected={ item.isSelected } onChange={ item.onChange } display={ item.display } />
        default:
          return <InputComponent />;
      }
    });

    return (
        <form id={ this.props.id } name={ this.props.name }>
            <FormHeaderComponent header={ this.props.header } />

            {/* 
              Setup handling of submit functions
              Setup handling of onchange function for inputs
            */}

            { formItems }
        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormComponent;
```

As you can see in the formItems I am trying to create the elements with the onChange function from the state passed in. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I am well aware also I can just make the form component a component that loads all children passed so you basically build the form in the login component without state but I would prefer that not be the case.

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing? Any undesired behavior? Your code looks like it should work, though you are missing the functions/binds in 2 of your items (syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing methods in state to be passed to children is usually a bad idea. I propose an alternative.

Consider the `onChange` function, that will still reside in `LoginComponent` and will be passed as a prop to the `<FormComponent />`

The handler is written as such that you'll be able to identify which child component called it, by taking it's `name` attribute too, eliminating the need to make a unique handler for each input.

LoginComponent:

```
  handleOnChangeEmail(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(`${name} changed to ${value}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="LoginComponent">
        <FormComponent
          id={this.state.id}
          name={this.state.name}
          onSubmit=""
          header={this.state.header}
          items={this.state.items}
          formOnChange={this.handleOnChangeEmail}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Then when you are iterating over and constructing your `InputComponent`, pass this to it's `onChange`:

FormComponent:

```
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const formItems = this.props.items.map(item => {
      switch (item.element) {
        case "input":
          return (
            <InputComponent
              type={item.type}
              id={item.id}
              name={item.name}
              placeholder={item.placeholder}
              value={item.value}
              onChange={this.props.formOnChange}
            />
          );
        case "checkbox":
          return (
            <CheckboxComponent
              id={item.id}
              name={item.name}
              value={item.value}
              selected={item.isSelected}
              onChange={this.props.formOnChange}
              display={item.display}
            />
          );
        default:
          return <InputComponent />;
      }
    });

    return (
      <form id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name}>
        <FormHeaderComponent header={this.props.header} />
        {formItems}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to `bind` your functions or use arrow functions.

Comment: I never thought about the idea of finding the element through the initial function by name. This is a good alternative! Thank you I will try this out!

Comment: I accepted your answer over the above since you provided more insight into how and why.

Comment: Bear in mind the `name` property is a valid attribute only for `<input>`

Comment: Yeah I will use the id field for determining what actually updated. But thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing same function handleChange to handle all form value change.

React onChange function pass event argument. With event argument perform necessary logic. Do not need onChange key in form object in state.

```js
 
 // use lodash library for array handling. 
 // yarn add lodash
 // import {indexOf} from "lodash"
 // using fat arrow will save from binding function in constructor.
 handleChange=({target})=> {
     const {items} = this.state;
     // target.name/id will give the element state can be update as required. 
     let index = indexOf(items, {name:target.name})
     items[index].value = target.value;
     this.setState({
       items
     })
  }

// remove handle change from items and just user it for all form value change.
<FormComponent id={ this.state.id } name={ this.state.name } handleChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit="" header={ this.state.header } items={ this.state.items } />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it did help solve my problem, the lodash library I will look into because I have never used it before but it looks promising. I accepted the answer below because he put more detail into why this is the better solution.